# Visual selection and clipboard

Tags: operating-system, clipboard

When we visually select a piece of text in an application, it gets copied to the clipboard and is available for other applications to read from.

I was curious to know how are the bytes corresponding to the visual selection transferred to the clipboard. Who is responsible for supplying the bytes corresponding to the visual selection in an application to the clipboard?